# Adding an If Statement into Html e-mail text in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add in an if statement half way through a HTML body of text I am using in VBA to send an e-mail.

I need to work out how to get the code to add extra hyperlinks if a cell in on one of the tabs has a value, there could be up to five that may need to be added.

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
            .Display
                .To = Accounts
                .Subject = "Consolidated Account Statement " &     myPolicynumber & " - " & mypolicyname
  If myhyperlink2 = "" Then
            .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>" & "<FONT-size=""11.0pt"">" & "Hi Accounts" & "<br><br>" & _
              " The <a href= " & myhyperlink & ">Account Statement</a>" & _
              " for " & myPolicynumber & " (" & mypolicyname & ") is ready to be created. " & "<br><br>" & "<br><br>" & _
              " The following Medical Extra Premium also need booking " & "<br><br>"

If Worksheets("FOR PA").Cells(13, 39).Value = "Medicals" Then

            " <a href= " & myhyperlinkMed1 & ">Medical Extra Premium 1</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
            " <a href= " & myhyperlinkMed1 & ">Medical Extra Premium 2</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
            " <a href= " & myhyperlinkMed1 & ">Medical Extra Premium 3</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
            " <a href= " & myhyperlinkMed1 & ">Medical Extra Premium 4</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
            " <a href= " & myhyperlinkMed1 & ">Medical Extra Premium 5</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
            " Kind Regards," &.HTMLBody
                .Send
         Else
                    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>" & "<FONT-size=""11.0pt"">" & "Hi Accounts" & "<br><br>" & _
              " The <a href= " & myhyperlink & ">Initial</a>" & " and the " & "<a href= " & myhyperlink2 & ">Final </a> & are ready to be put on the Account Statement  " & _
              " for " & myPolicynumber & " (" & mypolicyname & ") is ready to be created. " & "<br><br>" & _
              " Kind Regards," & .HTMLBody
                .Send
       End If
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: What's your question? Your code has multiple IF statements, so why can't you just add a new one as you already have? What issue are you having exactly?

Comment: I do currently have multiple if statements but I am trying not to create a further 10 further large statements with the full html body as it maybe that there is not always five Medical extra premiums. So I was hoping someone would be able to help me add an IF statement in the middle of the HTML Body, which would enable me to use one main HTML Body just with some variables in it.

Comment: @DanHigh did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the right thing, but you're missing a `.HTMLBody =` before one of the options:

```
If Worksheets("FOR PA").Cells(13, 39).Value = "Medicals" Then

        .HTMLBody = " <a href= " & myhyperlinkMed1 & ">Medical Extra Premium 1</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
                    " <a href= " & myhyperlinkMed1 & ">Medical Extra Premium 2</a>" & "<br><br>" & _
```